# Notation for binomial coefficient set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, binomial-coefficients

I've been searching for a way to express "the set of all combinations generated by taking $\binom{n}{k}$ items".  For example, if I have the set $\{3,7,6,5,9\}$, and I want the set of all sets that are formed by making $\binom{5}{4}$ choices, then the result would be

$\{\{3,7,6,5\}, \{3,6,5,9\}, \{3,7,5,9\}, \{3,7,6,9\}, \{7,6,5,9\}\}$

But I'm struggling to find a *notation* that describes this.  I can describe the number of results with $\binom{5}{4}=5$, but how do I describe the resulting set-of-sets itself?  The notation $5 \brace 4$ is already taken by Stirling numbers.  I've looked at articles and questions about sets, set theory, the binomial coefficient, and I've drawn a blank.

So, is there a standard notation?  (I feel that, surely, there must be!)  If there is, what is it?  And if there isn't, could anyone suggest a notation that would be halfway familiar to a reader?

Comment: $\binom54$ is $5$, and each of the sets you display have only $4$ elements. The only subset of $\{3,7,6,5,9\}$ that has $\binom54$ elements is $\{3,7,6,5,9\}$ itself!

Comment: $\binom{5}{4}=5$, so there are 5 unique sets in total (shown in the question), and each set has 4 elements. $\binom{5}{5}=1$, so there is 1 unique set in total ($\{3,7,6,5,9\}$), and that set has 5 elements.

Comment: How does "choosing $\binom54$ of the items" produce a set with less than $\binom54$ items in it?

Comment: It does not. There are 5 subsets, count them in my question.

Comment: x @Rhyme: I've counted. $\{3,7,6,5\}$ contains only $4$ items, countrary to your claim that you produced it by choosing $\binom 54=5$ of the items in $\{3,7,6,5,9\}$.

Comment: My 5 items are: first item = $\{3,7,6,5\}$, second item = $\{3,6,5,9\}$, third item = $\{3,7,5,9\}$, fourth item = $\{3,7,6,9\}$, fifth item = $\{7,6,5,9\}$. Note that I am counting the elements in the set of all sets possible by picking $\binom{5}{4}$. (would you like to move this to chat? we may be discussing at cross-purposes here...)

Comment: Your question expliclitly speaks about "the set of all sets that are formed by choosing $5$ items". The sets in your set have only $4$ members each, not $5$. If you want to speak about sets that are formed by choosing $4$ items, you should not describe them as "sets that are formed by choosing $5$ items", becuase $4$ and $5$ are different numbers, and none of your $4$-element sets represent a choice of $5$ items.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42938/discussion-between-rhyme-and-henning-makholm).

Comment: {3,7,6,5} is not a set that is formed by choosing 5 items. {3,6,5,9} is not a set that is formed by choosing 5 items. {3,7,5,9} is not a set that is formed by choosing 5 items. {3,7,6,9} is not a set that is formed by choosing 5 items. {7,6,5,9} is not a set that is formed by choosing 5 items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a notation for the set of all $k$-element subsets of some set $X$. There’s a standard notation for this: $[X]^k$. However, it’s most commonly found in set theory and some areas of combinatorics and for a more general audience is quite likely to be unfamiliar to some readers, so you’d do well to define it anyway.

**Added:** I don’t care for the notation myself, but it occurs to me that I have also seen the notation $\binom{X}k$ used, by analogy with the binomial coefficient itself. Here again it would be a good idea to define the notation if you use it.

Comment: Thank you very much, that is very comprehensive.  Might I ask if the different notations tend to be used in different fields?  I am writing for a Computer Science audience myself, and am specifically wondering whether one of these notations may be more familiar for that audience.  If not, I too find the first notation to be more accessible, and will likely default to defining & using it.

Comment: @Rhyme: You’re most welcome. I’ve seen the second notation only a few times; I don’t know whether that’s because it’s more common in fields that I don’t normally see, or whether it’s because it’s genuinely not very common at all. In particular, I’m afraid I don’t know how likely either is to be familiar to a computer science audience.

Answer (score 1):

> - The following notation is used by R.P. Stanley in *[Topics in Algebraic Combinatorics](http://www-math.mit.edu/~rstan/algcomb/algcomb.pdf)*. See section *Basic Notation* (p.6)
>
> \begin{array}{ccl}
> &2^S\qquad&\qquad \text{the set of all subsets of the set }  S\\
> &\binom{S}{k}\qquad&\qquad \text{the set of $k$-element subsets of } S\\
> \end{array}

We can find in section 1.2, p.23 in his classic *[Enumerative Combinatorics](http://math.mit.edu/~rstan/ec/ec1.pdf)*, ed. 2 also the preferred wording for the symbol.

> - Now define $\binom{S}{k}$ (sometimes denoted $S^{(k)}$ or otherwise, and read *$S$ choose $k$*) to be the set of all $k$-element subsets (or $k$-subsets) of $S$ ...