# Can a set be a member of its own power set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm new to set theory and I'm using actually an introduction to topology by Bert Mendelson that features some set theory questions. (side note, does anyone have a link to where the answers are for the books exercises?)

My question is the following, and give reasons:

true or false

For each set $A$, $A \in 2^A$

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) might be an interesting read.

Comment: What are the definitions of power set and $2^A$ in your textbook, and in what context does the question occur?

Comment: Yes that is true, $2^A$ is the set of all subsets of $A$ and indeed $A$ is a subset of $A$ and therefore an element of $2^A$.

Answer (score 20):

**Definition:** $2^A\cong P(A)=\{B:B\subseteq A\}$

**Hint:** $A\subseteq A$

Comment: B need not be a proper subset of A. So B $\subseteq$ A and not B $\subset$ A.

Comment: I use $\subset$ and $\subsetneq$ rather than $\subseteq$ and $\subset$. There is a confusion both ways using $\subset$. I guess we could use $\subseteq$ and $\subsetneq$ always, but since I wrote $A\subset A$, I thought it was clear that $\subset$ meant $\subseteq$. I will edit this answer.

Comment: @AditiNarware: The symbol $\subset$ is typically used for inclusion, not necessarily proper.

Comment: @copper.hat: conventions vary — many sources use $\subset$ just for proper inclusion, and $\subseteq$ for not-necessarily-proper.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine: I just picked 6 analysis/topology textbooks from my library (admittedly all a few decades old), all used $\subset$.

Answer (score 20):

Formally, there's a difference between $2^A$, which is the set of all functions $A\to\{0,1\}$, and the power set $\mathcal P(A)$, which is the set of all subsets of $A$.

$2^A$ and $\mathcal P(A)$ are in a natural bijective correspondence to each other, so it often is convenient not to distinguish strictly between them. But in this particular case I think we need to do so and say
$$ A\in\mathcal P(A) \quad\text{but}\quad A\notin 2^A $$

Comment: +1. As a caveat, though, I would note that $2^A$ gets used to refer to the powerset fairly frequently (even though this is indeed slightly incorrect).

Comment: @NoahSchweber I've never seen $2^A$ directly denote the powerset. It is only ever used when the cardinality is the interesting notion (in which case it doesn't matter).

Comment: I've seen $2^A$ used for the power set, for example [in the book that the OP is using](https://archive.org/stream/IntroductionToTopology/Mendelson-IntroductionToTopology#page/n11/mode/2up). So this is not an answer to the question.

Comment: Or, actually, this does give a yes/no answer the question "Is $A$ a member of its power set" but is not helpful to the OP.

Comment: Pedantically, we have $A \in 2^A \iff A = \varnothing$ when we notationally distinguish between the power set and the set of functions $A \to \{0,1\}$.

Comment: @Mario: It is not in fact uncommon to see $2^A$ used directly to denote the power set of $A$.

Comment: In type theory $2^A$ would denote a set that contains $2^A$ elements for a given $A$ (mostly because it's notationally equivalent to $A \rightarrow 2$). Correctness of this notation depends on the branch of mathematics.

Comment: I have often seen the notation $2^A$ used for power sets in the context of relaxed controls and differential inclusions.

Comment: Maybe you could include a definition of $2^A$ you are using (since there are multiple ways of defining ordered pairs and therefore multiple ways of defining a function $A \to \{0,1\}$).

Comment: The notation $2^A$ is also common in combinatorics. See e.g. *[this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1869403/notation-for-binomial-coefficient-set/1869735#1869735)*. Regards,

Comment: I've never seen that definition of $2^A$, I have only ever seen it as an alias for the power set $\mathcal{P}(A)$ (that doesn't necessarily make it "correct", whatever that means, but that is what I have experienced in common usage).

Answer (score 2):

Power set is nothing but the collection of all possible subsets of a given set. Clearly, $\emptyset$ and the set itself are included in the power set.
For example:
$A={1,2,3}$
Then the subsets of $A$ are:
{$\emptyset$}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {1,2}, {2,3}, {1,3} )and lastly, {1,2,3}
These are the elements in the power set of A represented as:
P(A) ={ {$\emptyset$}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {1,2},{2,3},{1,3},{1,2,3} }
Hope it helps!

Comment: `$\emptyset$` showing as $\emptyset$ or `$\varnothing$` showing as  $\varnothing$ might be better than `$\phi$` showing as  $\phi$