# Math notation for iterating over pairs of edges

Tags: graph-theory, permutations, notation

I have a graph and I would like to iterate over each pair of edge. Is there a syntactically nicer way of indicating this other that my current solution:

$$
(u, v), (x, y) \in E, (u, v) \neq (x, y)
$$

Comment: You can also define $e_1, e_2 \in E, e_1 \ne e_2$

Comment: Consider using words. 90% of the time when people are looking for "math notation" for something, they're trying to say something that is easier to explain with words than with symbols. There's nothing unmathematical about being clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use $\binom{E}{2} = \{\{e_1,e_2\} \subset E | e_1 \neq e_2\}$. It is not totally standard but its quite common to see it especially in graph theory.

see also [Notation for binomial coefficient set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1869403/notation-for-binomial-coefficient-set)

> - The following notation is used by R.P. Stanley in *[Topics in Algebraic Combinatorics](http://www-math.mit.edu/%7Erstan/algcomb/algcomb.pdf)*. See section *Basic Notation* (p.6)

> \begin{array}{ccl}
> &2^S\qquad&\qquad \text{the set of all subsets of the set }  S\\
> &\binom{S}{k}\qquad&\qquad \text{the set of $k$-element subsets of } S\\
> \end{array}

Comment: Thanks, this is a clearer option compared to what I had before.